# Problem in dyanamic textbox validation

Tags: javascript, html

my code is as follows:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function doit() {

            for (j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
                var a = document.getElementById('textbox' + j);
                if (a.value != "")
                    alert("You entered: " + a.value)
                else
                    alert("please enter something");
            }
        }
        function change() {

            my_proj.innerHTML = "";
            for (j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {

                my_proj.innerHTML = my_proj.innerHTML + '<input type="text" id="textbox' + j + '" runat="server"></input>';



            }
        }
        </script>

<form id="form1" runat="server" name="form1">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" onChange="change()">
            <asp:ListItem>-Select-</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    <div id="my_proj">
    <input type="submit" onclick="doit()" />

    </div>
    </form>
```

But while running it is giving me the following error:

Parser Error Message: 'textbox' + j + '' is not a valid identifier.

Can someone please suggest me a solution??? thanx in advance

Comment: AS3-er here, I can't see anything wrong with your javascript, through you didn't declare j. Maybe you don't have to in JS, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
my_proj.innerHTML = "";
```

in `change()`, it will delete the submit button so I'm not sure how you tried submitting. But try moving the button outside of the div

```
<div id="my_proj">


</div>
<input type="submit" onclick="doit()" />
```

Here's an equivalent [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vTdzh/) that you can check out.

Comment: It worked.. now i will integrate it in my project, lets see it works der or not.. Thanks for it!! :)

Comment: No im getting the same error.. 'textbox' + j + '' is not a valid identifier. please give me some soln. iv also used it before and it worked. for the 1st time im trying to use it with .net and this error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your 'change' function you just refer to my_proj as if it is a global variable, from the snippet, this doesn't look to be the case, so perhaps the following will help:

```
var my_proj = document.getElementById('my_proj');
```

Before you clear the innerHTML.

I don't recognise the exception you mention, but perhaps it is a red herring.